# Where am I in the map?

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I get the occupancy value from the map at my robots position? The map is increasing dynamically as my robot moves around, right? Hence the (0,0) index of the data array may shift as my map expands. What I want is the occupancy value at the very position of my robot. How can I achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10268/where-am-i-in-the-map?/) by [koloman](https://answers.ros.org/users/696/koloman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-06-15

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To know where the robot is in the map, you want to transform the origin of the `base_link` frame into the `map` frame.

In addition to the map, SLAM systems ([gmapping](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping) and [karto](http://ros.org/wiki/karto)) publish [transform data](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf).  In particular, they [provide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping#Provided_tf_Transforms) the transform from the `map` frame to the `odom` frame.  Another node (which one will depend on what kind of robot you're using) should already be publishing the transform from the `odom` frame to the `base_link` frame.

The [tf library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) will chain those transforms together for you.  The details will depend on whether you're writing in C++ or Python; check the tf documentation.  As an example, from the command-line, you can do this while the SLAM system is running:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo map base_link
```

Note: frames names are configurable, and your system may use different names from the ones I gave above.  But the semantics of them is the same.

Given the robot's pose in the `map` frame, if you want the corresponding index into the occupancy grid map, you'd do something like this:

```
grid_x = (unsigned int)((map_x - map.info.origin.position.x) / map.info.resolution)
grid_y = (unsigned int)((map_y - map.info.origin.position.y) / map.info.resolution)
```

In principle, you should also account for the orientation of the origin (`map.info.origin.orientation`), but in practice there's no rotation.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-06-20**:
I updated the answer with some code for that pose-to-grid conversion.

**Comment by [koloman](https://answers.ros.org/users/696/koloman/) on 2011-06-17**:
Allright. So all I have to do is transform the base_link into the map frame. Further I just take the pose, devide the coordinate components by the map resolution and there I have the correct indices for the map data array? what if they are negative? shouldn't I somehow account for the map origin?

**Comment by [Kushaagra](https://answers.ros.org/users/22696/kushaagra/) on 2015-06-08**:
Are these coordinates grid_x and grid_y in the /map frame. I have an object with its location static w.r.t the /map frame. So as the map changes dynamically (so does the location of object but static w.r.t map), will these coordinates also remain static?

**Comment by [Michdo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/39516/michdo93/) on 2019-01-17**:
Where do map_x and map_y come from? From map or from base_link? How can I get map_x or map_y what should I "calculate"?